# Open door when more than 20 coins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make it so a door in unity opens when you have collected 20 coins. and then it opens when you touch it. but for some reason. when i touch it with 0, 1, 2 etc coins it still opens. how do i prevent this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Player_Controller : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed;
public Text countText;
private Rigidbody rb;
private int count;
public float volume;
public Text eye;



AudioSource audio;
void Start()
{

    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    SetCountText();
    eye.text = "";
}


void FixedUpdate()
{

    float moveHorizonal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizonal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);

}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("pickup"))
    {
        audio.Play(); //Play it

        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText();
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("pickup2"))
    {
        audio.Play(); //Play it

        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 10;
        SetCountText();
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("eye"))
    {
        audio.Play(); //Play it

        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 9999999;
        SetCountText();
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("door") && count <= 20)
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = 0;
    }


}

void SetCountText()
{
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
    if (count >= 9001)
    {
        eye.text = "You hit the bull's eye! ALL THE POINTS!";
    }
}
}
```

Update: I used the wrong character here. the < is supposed to be >. but the problem now is that, since its a trigger, you roll right through. how can i make it solid, but still a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("door") && count <= 20)
```

You're saying if the count is less than OR 20 then open the door.

Change it to:

```
else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("door") && count >= 20)
```

This then says at least 20 OR more

This [tutorial](http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/comparison-operators/) may shed some light on the operators you can use :)

Comment: Yeah, i figured i did something wrong like that. but the thing is now. that i can roll through the door regardless of if i have the 20 points or not. i know this is because its a trigger. so is there a way to make a trigger still have collisions?

Comment: @MichaDeHaan I'm afraid I'm not best placed to answer that query, I'd recommend searching here / asking it as a separate question; I just saw a C# problem :P

Comment: Actually i jyst figured it out :I all i had to do is add a child to the door that is solid. since when you remove the parent, all the childs also get removed. thanks anyways!